# Riemann-Roch to compute $h^0(F)$ where $F$ is a general fiber on a rational elliptic surface

Tags: algebraic-geometry, sheaf-cohomology, divisors-algebraic-geometry

Let $X$ be a relatively minimal rational elliptic surface over a number field $k$, with elliptic fibration $\pi:X\to\Bbb{P}^1$.

It is well known that the anticanonical divisor $-K_X$ is linearly equivalent to a general fiber $F$ and $\chi(0)=1$, where $\chi(D):=h^0(D)-h^1(D)+h^2(D)$ and $h^i(D):=\dim_kH^0(X,\mathcal{O}_X(D))$ for any divisor $D$ in $X$.

Since the linear system $|F|$ defines the fibration $\pi:X\to\Bbb{P}^1$, I should expect $h^0(F)=2$, but I still don't now how to prove it.

Since $F^2=0$ and $F\cdot K_X=-F^2=0$, by Riemann-Roch for surfaces $\chi(F)=1$.

By Serre duality, $h^2(F)=h^0(K_X-F)=h^0(-2F)=0$, since $F$ is effective. Consequently $h^0(F)-h^1(F)=1$, but I don't know how to treat $h^1(F)$.

Again by duality, $h^1(F)=h^1(-2F)$, by I don't think this helps.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the exact sequence
$$
0 \to \mathcal{O}_X \to \mathcal{O}_X(F) \to \mathcal{O}_F(F) \to 0.
$$
The cohomology of the first term have dimensions $(1,0,0)$, because these are birational invariants and $X$ is rational. Furthermore,
$$
\mathcal{O}_F(F) \cong \mathcal{N}_{F/X} \cong \mathcal{O}_F
$$
because $F$ is the fiber of a morphism. Since this is an elliptic curve, its cohomology has dimensions $(1,1,0)$. Now from the exact sequence it follows that the cohomology of $\mathcal{O}_X(F)$ have dimensions $(2,1,0)$.

Comment: How do we define the exact sequence?

Comment: I'm not sure what $\mathcal{O}_F(F)$ means

Comment: The sequence is obtained by tensoring $0 \to \mathcal{O}_X(-F) \to \mathcal{O}_X \to \mathcal{O}_F \to 0$ with $\mathcal{O}_X(F)$ and $\mathcal{O}_F(F)$ means $\mathcal{O}_X(F)\vert_F$.

Comment: But if $U\subset X$ is open, how do we define $\mathcal{O}_X(-F)(U)\to \mathcal{O}_X(U)$? I know this is boring, but I'm just trying to make sure I understand

Comment: This is multiplication with the equation of $F$ (restricted to $U$).

Comment: thank you so much

Comment: One last question: you mention two isomorphisms, namely $\mathcal{O}_F(F)\simeq \mathcal{N}_{F/X}\simeq\mathcal{O}_F$, which occur because $F$ is a fiber. If $F$ was not a fiber, which of these isomorphisms would fail?

Comment: @rmdmc89: The second.